# including header files in one another

Tags: c, header, include

if I have two header files

`a.h` and `b.h`

can I include "a.h" in b.h

and also include "b.h" in "a.h" ?

Comment: It's normally best to have a dependency in only one direction.

Comment: You could try to add `#pragma once`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's not a very good idea. If you really must, you can prevent recursion with the use of include guards (which are a good idea regardless).

In `a.h`:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

#endif
```

and `b.h`

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work. The preprocessor just replaces your `#include"xyz.h"` with the actual file, so this would end in an endless recursion.

Comment: If the header files are guarded, as they normally are, then it would not.  The real problem is making the dependencies seen by the C compiler work in either direction.